# Can the NSG be applied to the Subnet AFTER the Azure SQL Managed Instance is deployed into the subnet?

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

Can the NSG be applied to the Subnet AFTER the SQL MI is deployed into the subnet?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-vnet-configuration

We are getting the following error when saving:

“Failed to save subnet 'managed-sql-dev-corp'. Error: 'Found conflicts with NetworkIntentPolicy. Details: Subnet or Virtual Network cannot have resources or properties which conflict with network intent policy.”

Is the “Network Intent Policy” created by Azure Service or one of my own policies?

Answer (score 4):

Once Managed Instance is deployed in the valid network/subnet, it will enforce some "Intent Policies" that prevent you from making some configurations that can invalidate the subnet.

As an example, Managed Instance can be deployed only in the subnet that don't contains other VMs. Once you deploy Managed Instance, it will setup intent rule that don't allow you to create VMs in this subnet and make the subnet invalid after deployment. Without these rules, you would be able to block access to Managed Instance. It cannot block everything, but this Intent Policy is the first-line of defense that Managed Instance uses to prevent someone to reconfigure the subnet.

Below is an example of the outbound rules that could be used in NSG.

[image]

- Rule allow_management_inbound allows management traffic to reach the
  instance.
- Rule allow_misubnet_inbound allows communication between
  the virtual machines that form Managed Instance cluster.
- Rule allow_health_probe allows health check from the virtual machines
  host. Without it service fabric will think that nodes are unhealthy
  and block the access.
- Rule allow_tds_inbound is optional but without it yon can’t access the Managed Instance. It is advised to narrow its IP range as much as possible.

Priority numbers need not to be as depicted, but top 3 rules have to be of higher priority than any Deny rules.

To be compliant with Managed Instance Network Intent Policy, NSG must have rules that are numbered on picture as 100 and 200 on the top of the list.

[image]

- Rule allow_management_outbound allows management traffic to reach the services managed instance depends upon.
- Rule allow_misubnet_outbound allows communication between the virtual machines that form Managed Instance cluster.

Priority numbers need not to be as depicted, but top 2 rules have to be of higher priority than any Deny rules.

Managed Instance additional features may require additional ports to be open. This would be defined in the specific feature documentation.

Comment: is there any way to enable service endpoints for storage accounts after the SQL MI has been created? `"Details: Subnet or Virtual Network cannot have resources or properties which conflict with network intent policy. Service endpoints [Microsoft.Storage] on Subnet are not allowed as provided in Network Intent Policy:".  ` Any reason this is explicitly denied - want to use FW restricted storage accounts for [RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?