# Managed Instance deployment failed due to error related to preparation of network intent policy

Tags: azure, pulumi, azure-sql-managed-instance

Following Pulumi doc [Create managed instance with all properties](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/sql/managedinstance/#create-managed-instance-with-all-properties) and trying to create Managed Instance with code below:

```cs
//
// spokeManagedInstanceSubnet -> delegated to "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances"
// spokeManagedInstanceSubnet -> does not have any other resource (i.e. VM)
// 
var spokeManagedInstanceSubnet = new Subnet($"{SpokeVirtualNetwork}.{ManagedInstanceSubnet}", new AzureNative.Network.SubnetArgs {
    // ... ... ...
}, new CustomResourceOptions { DependsOn = { spokeVnet } });


//
// Create Managed Instance
//
var mainManagedInstanceArgs = config.RequireObject<JsonElement>(MainManagedInstanceArgs);

var mainMiName = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetName();
var mainMiSku = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetSku();
var mainMiTier = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetTier();
var mainMiVCores = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetInt(VCores);
var mainMiStorageSizeInGB = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetInt(StorageSizeInGB);
var mainMiStorageAccountType = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetString(StackConfigKeys.StorageAccountType);
var mainMiAdminId = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetString(AdministratorLoginId);
var mainMiAdminPassword = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetString(AdministratorLoginPassword);
var mainMiLicenseType = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetString(StackConfigKeys.LicenseType);
var mainMiCollation = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetString(Collation);
var mainMiTimezoneId = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetString(TimezoneId);
var mainMiMinimalTlsVersion = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetString(MinimalTlsVersion);
var mainMiPublicDataEndpointEnabled = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetBool(PublicDataEndpointEnabled);
var mainMiTags = mainManagedInstanceArgs.GetTags();

var mainManagedInstance = new ManagedInstance(MainManagedInstance, new ManagedInstanceArgs {
    ResourceGroupName = mainResourceGroup.Name,
    SubnetId = spokeManagedInstanceSubnet.Id,
    ManagedInstanceName = mainMiName,
    Sku = new AzureNative.Sql.Inputs.SkuArgs {
        Name = mainMiSku,
        Tier = mainMiTier,
    },
    VCores = mainMiVCores,
    StorageSizeInGB = mainMiStorageSizeInGB,
    StorageAccountType = mainMiStorageAccountType,
    ManagedInstanceCreateMode = ManagedServerCreateMode.Default,
    AdministratorLogin = mainMiAdminId,
    AdministratorLoginPassword = mainMiAdminPassword,
    LicenseType = mainMiLicenseType,
    ProxyOverride = ManagedInstanceProxyOverride.Default,
    Collation = mainMiCollation,
    TimezoneId = mainMiTimezoneId,
    MinimalTlsVersion = mainMiMinimalTlsVersion,
    PublicDataEndpointEnabled = mainMiPublicDataEndpointEnabled,
    Tags = mainMiTags
}, new CustomResourceOptions { DependsOn = { spokeManagedInstanceSubnet } });
```

Getting following errors:

> Pulumi Error: `error: update failed. Code="Failed" Message="The async operation failed."`
> Error shown in Azure portal: `managed Instance create operation failed`
> Virtual network activity log: `Managed Instance deployment failed due to conflict with the following error related to preparation of network intent policy: Network security group is required for subnet`

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935446/can-the-nsg-be-applied-to-the-subnet-after-the-azure-sql-managed-instance-is-dep) but did not solve my problem.

**How to create Managed Instance in the delegated subnet ?**

According to Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/connectivity-architecture-overview#service-aided-subnet-configuration)

> To address customer security and manageability requirements, SQL Managed Instance is transitioning from manual to service-aided subnet configuration.

So, user just needs to delegate subnet (which I did) and then Azure (ARM) should take care of the rest (NSG, Route table etc.)

## Update 2021.11.21

I added NSG and Route table to ManagedInstanceSubnet and getting followings (in Azure portal):

> Step 1/3 Request validation: Completed
> Step 2/3 Virtual Cluster resize/creation: Completed
> Step 3/3 SQL Instance Cleanup: Failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to create Azure SQL Managed Instance by doing the followings (for "operation timed out" issue, see update below to resolve):**

1. Assigned "`SQL Managed Instance Contributor`" role to the service principal used by Pulumi
2. Created NSG and added NSG rules (ignored property `NetworkSecurityGroupArgs.SecurityRules`)
3. Crated Route Table (ignored property `RouteTableArgs.Routes`)
4. Managed Instance Subnet:

   - Subnet is delegated to `"Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances"`
   - NSG is attached to Subnet
   - Route Table is attached to Subnet

### Update 2021.12.03 - solution to "operation timed out error"

```cs
var operationTimeoutLimit = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);

var fpManagedInstance = new ManagedInstance(
    name: "FailoverPartnerManagedInstance",
    args: new ManagedInstanceArgs {
        // props
    },
    options: new CustomResourceOptions {
        CustomTimeouts = new CustomTimeouts {
            Create = operationTimeoutLimit,
            Update = operationTimeoutLimit,
            Delete = operationTimeoutLimit,
        }
    }
);
```

Timeout related question and answer: [Pulumi stack update failed due to operation timed out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126305/pulumi-stack-update-failed-due-to-operation-timed-out-error)