# Pulumi stack update failed due to operation timed out error

Tags: azure, pulumi, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am trying to create Azure SQL Managed Instance using C# (Pulumi Azure Native). When executing `pulumi up -s dev`, getting `operation timed out` error as following:

[image]

(*provisioning Managed Instance is a long running operation and in case of Pulumi, it is taking around 4 hours mentioned that when we create Managed Instance using Azure portal, it does not take that much time*)

I tried multiple times and that error is happening exactly after 2 hours. Followings are the issues due to `operation timed out` error:

- After 2 hours, Pulumi cli gave `error: operation timed out`, but I checked Azure portal & (after around 4 hours) Managed Instance was created successfully. I connected to Managed Instance using SSMS via public endpoint and restored `AdventureWorks2019.bak` successfully
- Although Managed Instance was created successfully, Pulumi does not recognize that Managed Instance was provisioned. So executing `pulumi preview -s dev` or `pulumi up -s dev` gives "`+ 1 to create`" means Pulumi will try to cerate Managed Instance again (and will fail since Managed Instance already exists)

**Why `operation timed out` error is occurring and how to solve it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like 2 hours is a default timeout for this resource type. You can overwrite it with [CustomTimeouts](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/resources/#customtimeouts) option like

```
new ManagedInstance("managedinstance", new ManagedInstanceArgs
{
    ..
}, new CustomResourceOptions
{
    CustomTimeouts = new CustomTimeouts
    {
        Create = TimeSpan.FromHours(4),
        Update = TimeSpan.FromHours(4),
    }
});
```

Comment: I was able to create Managed Instance using C# Pulumi Azure Native (took around 3 hours).